# Strange Opera issue about window.open

Tags: javascript, opera

I am designing a new bookmarklet and I am testing it on Opera.

This is my code:

```
javascript:(function(){var a=window.open('http://www.google.com','Ok','left='+((window.screenLeft||window.screenX)+10)+',top='+((window.screenY||window.screenTop)+0)+',height=200px,width=400px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1,location=1,links=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0');window.setTimeout(function(){a.focus()},250)})();
```

The problem is that the new window doesn't appear on the top but at about 200px from the top ( in other browsers like internet explorer, firefox and chrome it works well ).

So, Why this window doesn't appear on the top in Opera ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that in Opera, both *window.screenY* and *window.screenTop* are defined, and *screenY* seems to always equal 0 which is a [falsy](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) value in JavaScript, so

```
window.screenY||window.screenTop
```

would always return window.screenTop in Opera while you actually need the first value.

The proper way of checking is:

```
'screenY' in window ? window.screenY : window.screenTop
```

Here is your complete code, I also updated the check for *screenLeft* / *screenX*:

```
javascript:(function(){var a=window.open('http://www.google.com','Ok','left='+(('screenLeft' in window ? window.screenLeft : window.screenX)+10)+',top='+(('screenY' in window ? window.screenY : window.screenTop)+0)+',height=200px,width=400px,resizable=1,alwaysRaised=1,location=1,links=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0');window.setTimeout(function(){a.focus()},250)})();
```

Good luck.